# Opposite of "mixed reactions"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am looking for a good opposite for "mixed reactions". For example:

> The movies with the most mixed reactions from viewers are: ...

Now I want to use the opposite:

> The movies with the most [words meaning agreement in reactions] from viewers are: ...

Note that I used "agreement" above. That's intentional because I am not looking for something that conveys the movies were great or terrible. I am just trying to convey that, say, most (> 70-80%) people rated it X out of 5 scale, where X can be 2 or 4 (it doesn't matter). I have "homogeneous reactions" in my mind but I was wondering is there any better alternative?

Comment: How about _consistent_?

Comment: @Glorfindel "Unanimous reactions", sounds good. Thanks. I think it's better than "homogeneous reactions", especially now that I see "homogeneous reactions" is a [widely used term](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22homogeneous%20reactions%22) in Chemistry.

Comment: @KateBunting "consistent reactions", that sounds good too. Thanks. A quick google search tells me there are 14,700 results for ["consistent reactions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22consistent%20reactions%22) and 1470 results for ["unanimous reactions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unanimous%20reactions%22). So it is more widely used... however *unanimous* sounds more natural to me in this context... I am not sure... it's a hard choice!

Comment: I would say *the most agreed-upon reactions*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*unanimous*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unanimous), from the Latin 'unus animus' meaning 'one mind' might work. It's mostly used when there's a 100% agreement, but I found some instances (e.g. [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=pv6MBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=%22unanimous+reactions%22&source=bl&ots=zpID3G_nMX&sig=tOUfk0gPhJBbFu6mXyS_hNw2wEw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-5P__8dPeAhUMKVAKHWOdBLEQ6AEwBHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22unanimous%20reactions%22&f=false)) where it's used comparatively.

> 1 : ... having the agreement and consent of all

<sub>(source: Merriam-Webster)</sub>

That would make your quote

> The movies with the most unanimous reactions from viewers are: ...